# Decouple controller logic from Unity3D GUI controls using C#, like fade OnGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm failing to understand how to decouple business logic of a controller and view for Unity3D GUI controls.

For example, if I have a `GUI.Box`, how would I implement a controller to fade in or out from the `OnGUI` lifecycle stage of the view?

**View**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleView : MonoBehaviour {

    protected void OnGUI () {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), "Title");
    }

}
```

If I instantiate a controller to change `alpha` of `GUI.color` it would need notification of `Update()` from the main view thread.

To roughly encapsulate functionality, if this were a single script it could be implemented as:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleView : MonoBehaviour {

    private Color color;

    protected void Start () {
        color = Color.white;
    }

    protected void OnGUI () {
        GUI.color = color;
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), "Title");
    }

    protected void Update () {
        if(color.a > 0)
            color.a -= Time.deltaTime / 3;
    }

}
```

Akin to how iTween animates changes to properties using `iTween.fadeTo(gameObject, ...` how can this be implemented for Unity3d GUI controls using statements like `FadeOut()`?

There's probably no way to target individual GUI controls unless multiple controller instances are specified `OnGUI()`.  However, it would be cool to control isolated GUI instances such as fading in a `GUI.Box` followed by `GUI.Label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleView : MonoBehaviour {

private Color color;
private bool bFadeIn = false;
private bool bFadeOut = false;

protected void Start () {
    color = Color.white;
} 
public void FadeOut(){
    bFadeOut = true;
    bFadeIn = false;
}    
public void FadeIn(){
    bFadeIn = true;
    bFadeOut = false;
}

protected void OnGUI () {
    GUI.color = color;
    GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), "Title");
}

protected void Update () {
    if(bFadeOut && color.a > 0.0)color.a -= Time.deltaTime / 3;
    if(bFadeIn && color.a < 1.0)color.a += Time.deltaTime / 3;
}
}
```

You might also want to include a flag to determine when the control is invisible and, if invisible, skip the full GuiRender function.

Comment: This would work for inheritance, using this as a base class; however, what I'm trying to apply is code from a different class updating `OnGUI`.  Like the way `iTween.FadeTo` is implemented, I'm trying to understand how that functionality could be applied to Unity3D GUI.  But thanks for your answer!  If I receive nothing else I will assume inheritance is the only option.

Comment: So let me see if I understand.  If you have GUI Foo attached some object and then a script BAR on another object you want BAR to be able to do something like "fade(Foo)"?  If you want to avoid inheritance you would have to create a manager and register "fadable" guis with it, possibly tied to a dictionary so you can access them by name.  IIRC, Unity doesn't have named GUI elements.  You'd also have to override the default OnGUI with your own that is called by the manager's OnGUI.  That way modifications to GUI.color are applied correctly.

Comment: Fair enough - it seems a lack of named GUI elements is the root cause of implementation complexity; perhaps combined with GUI accessed only via a `MonoBehaviour` `OnGUI()`.

Comment: It's a pain, I had to write a whole manager to class to simulate MouseOver() to keep the clicks from going through.  Unity3D version 4 is supposed to have a new GUI system, might be it gets a much needed update.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is what you are looking for, but its a simple way to add fade effect to gui..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

/**Fade In/Out Instructions:
* 1.Create bool fadeIn. Create float alpha.
* 2.Call Fade() method at start of OnGUI().
* 3.Put 'GUI.color = new Color(1,1,1,alpha)' above the elements you want to fade'.
* 4.To fade in, fadeIn = true. 
* 5.To fade out, fadeIn = false.
* 6.To deactivate buttons on fade out, wrap gui in 'if(alpha > 0)'
**/

public class MainMenuGUI : MonoBehaviour {

    int buttonWidth;
    int buttonHeight;

    public float alpha;
    public bool fadeIn;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    buttonWidth = 100;
    buttonHeight = 50;

    fadeIn = true;
}

void OnGUI(){

    Fade();

    GUI.color = new Color(1,1,1,alpha);

    if(alpha > 0)
    {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect ((Screen.width/2)-50, (Screen.height/2)-(buttonHeight*4/2), 100, 50), "PLAY"))
        {
            fadeIn = false;
            Debug.Log("Play pressed");
        }

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect ((Screen.width/2)-50, ((Screen.height/2)-(buttonHeight*4/2)+ buttonHeight), 100, 50), "SCORES")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Scores pressed");
        }

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect ((Screen.width/2)-50, ((Screen.height/2)-(buttonHeight*4/2)+ buttonHeight*2), 100, 50), "OPTIONS")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Options pressed");
        }

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect ((Screen.width/2)-50, ((Screen.height/2)-(buttonHeight*4/2)+ buttonHeight*3), 100, 50), "EXIT")) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Exit pressed");
        }
    }
}

void Fade(){
    if(fadeIn){
        alpha = Mathf.Clamp(alpha+0.01f,0,1);
    }else{
        alpha = Mathf.Clamp(alpha-0.01f,0,1);   
    }
}

}
```

Good luck on your game :)